# Improper output via char pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Look at the following program

```
int main()
{
 char p[3]="bug";
 puts(p);
 char *a=p;
 puts(a);
 return 0;
}
```

For the 1st puts i get correct output (i.e) "bug"
But for the 2nd puts i get output as "bug↓ ("

1. Why for the second output junk value is appended at the end?
2. char *a points to same memory location as char p[3]. Why it is not able to detect the end '\0'?

Comment: `"bug"` is 4 characters long. The null terminator goes in the array. There are nasal demons around here somewhere.

Comment: @nmichaels I never heard about nasal demons before. Thanks for that, awesome :)

Comment: @nmichaels confused since 1st puts was able to detect '\0' and gave proper output. Thats why this question raised

Answer (score 5):

To store `"bug"` + the 0 terminator **you need 4 chars**, you only allocated 3. Try:

```
char p[] = "bug";
```

<strike>I suspect the first `puts` works because the compiler does something funny and can detect the size.</strike>

nmichaels has a better explanation: *The first one works because `char *a` goes right after char p[3] on the stack. The null terminator becomes an initial value for a and as long as a stays uninitialized, p ends in a zero.*

Comment: The first one works because `char *a` goes right after `char p[3]` on the stack. The null terminator becomes an initial value for `a` and as long as `a` stays uninitialized, `p` ends in a zero. That's not behavior you can rely on. Technically the behavior is undefined.

Comment: how i was able to get proper output for puts? eventhough i allocated 3 bytes

Comment: nmichaels nailed it.  You allocated three bytes **and a pointer**.  Assigning to `a` changed what was seen at `p[4]`.

Comment: IOW if you re-arrange the code so that both `puts()` happen after `char *a=p;`, then both should show the same behavior.  Good catch, @nmichaels.

Comment: @JoeFish doesn't char *a belongs automatic storage class and won't it have garbage value as default value?

Comment: @intex0075 Nope. `char *a` is on the stack and it may contain anything.

Comment: @nmichaels ^^ Yea thats what i was asking. char *a is stored in stack. This means it is a local variable belonging to auto storage class. The default value of local variable may be anything (garbage value). But in mycase for the above program how everytime *a is having '\0' ?? when its not initialized

Comment: @intex0075 Garbage, right. **So there's not guarantee it won't be 0**.

Comment: @intex0075 cnicutar has it correct - especially if you're running in a debugger (at least in MSVC), the memory will be initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

char[4] !!! Don't forget the \0 at the end!